# OpenJPA not taking full column name in query

Tags: jpql, openjpa

I am using OpenJPA and doing the mapping using orm.xml. For certain cases where my column name length is more than some number of characters then jpql while generating sql query generates the column name as only upto some number of characters.

If i have a mapping as below

```
<entity name="OneOffSystemTemplateVariableValue" class="financing.tools.docgen.models.OneOffSystemTemplateVariableValue">
    <table name="modification_variable_values"/>
    <attribute-override name="id">
      <column name="modification_variable_values_id"/>
    </attribute-override>
    .....
   </attributes>
  </entity>
```

When i run a simple query on `OneOffSystemTemplateVariableValue`, it generated my query as below

```
SELECT t0.**MODIFICATION_VARIABLE_VALUES_I**, t0.create_timestamp, t0.create_id, t0.last_update_timestamp, t0.last_update_id, t0.modification_object_id, t0.variable_name, t0.variable_value FROM Administrator.modification_variable_values t0 WHERE t0.one_off_template_id = ?
```

Here for  `MODIFICATION_VARIABLE_VALUES_ID` column if i change column name to MOD_VARIABLE_VALUES_ID then my query works good.

So sql generated is not taking full column name length.

I have not set the `maxColumnNameLength` anywhere in my application.

Can you tell me how can i set the value of column name length so that i may not face this problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, you would set the following property in your persistence.xml file.

```
openjpa.jdbc.DBDictionary=mysql(maxColumnNameLength=256)
```

For other databases refer to the [OpenJPA user manual](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/latest/docs/docbook/manual.html#ref_guide_dbsetup_dbsupport). I'd also be interested in knowing which database you're using so we might be able to fix this max column issue.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution. I am using DB2 and adding below line to persistence.xml resolved the issue.